# Short story about a lady visiting a conference for multiverse versions of herself?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I would appreciate some help finding a story I read on lightspeedmagazine.com whose title I've forgotten.

The details I recall are:

- The lady had a job involving investigation in some form
- There is a pre-party which she skips out on
- Sometime early during the conference a version of herself is murdered
- When she comes across the scene of the crime, she finds another version of herself there, though she appears innocent

Edit: Some extra details

- I read it sometime within the last two years
- It was a single written piece not a pdf piece

Comment: Was that a single piece of fiction or was it in one of those PDFs they make available? (You can [edit] that info in your post) also - more or less when did you read it?

Comment: @Jenayah updated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is most likely “And Then There Were (N-One)” by Sarah Pinsker

- The viewpoint character is an insurance claims investigator
- There is a murder
- All characters involved in the murder (victims, investigator, suspects) are alternate timeline versions of the main character

The only difference is that in appeared in *Uncanny*, issue 15, March/April 2017. You can read it [here](https://uncannymagazine.com/article/and-then-there-were-n-one/)

Comment: It was also read on Escape Pod as part of their experiments with multi-part episodes. Starting at [episode 652](http://escapepod.org/2018/11/01/escape-pod-652-and-then-there-were-n-one-part-1/).